# Xcode Error signing Failed to create provisioning profile and No profiles for 'com.photo.appwall' were found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, signing

I am having issues signing my application.

- Failed to create provisioning profile.
- No profiles for 'com.photo.appwall' were found.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Do you have access to an iOS device?  If so, plug one into your Mac and build the app to it.  Xcode will add the device to your development provisioning profile.  If you don't have any iOS devices, it is a bit more complicated.  Is this a paid Apple developer account?

Comment: it can be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133060/xcode-signing-failed-to-create-provisioning-profile

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems self explanatory: you need to register your test device on the Apple's developer portal.

- Log in Apple's Developer portal
- Click `Certificates, IDs & Profiles`
- Click `Devices` | `All`
- Click the `+` button and add your device UDID

Xcode should be able to do this for you if you plug your device with your computer then select it in menu:

- (Xcode 8) `Window` | `Devices`
- (Xcode 9) `Window` | `Devices and Simulators`