# Xcode Signing Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I subscribed to the App Developer program. I paid the fee. I've done Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. I added the app to App Store Connect.

[xcode signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnWSx.png)

I am getting the errors above. I don't have an iPhone phone. I'm developing on my macbook computer.

[xcode device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtosN.png)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45906399/4376309) address your question?

Comment: @peacetype The problem is the same but the answer didn't work. It asks for a Device name and Device ID (UDID). How do I add this. I am working on the simulator. I don't have a real iPhone phone.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in image that "Automatically Manage Signing" is enabled for this Xcode project. So Xcode is trying to create the provisioning profile for you but not able to create it.

B'coz you need to add account in Xcode from Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Click on + icon at bottom to add a new developer account.

[image]

You need to create provisioning profiles.

[image]

Once you have created provisioning profile, download it and install on your machine.

Please make sure the certificate used in cretation of the provisioning profile must be in your machine's keychain.

If those certificates not installed in your keychiain then you will see certificate issue in Xcode.

But I would recommend to create provisioning profile manually from apple developer portal as you can see and mainly you can know that which certificate and devices are used in the profile.

You can create following provisioning profiles for your app.

**Development Profile**

- You will be able to run/debug app on real device.
- The device must be added into the profile.
- This can be used for only development purpose.

**Adhoc Profile**

- You will be able to install app on real device but not able to debug it.
- The device must be added in profile to install app on it.
- It acts as a release build but not a actually release build.
- Generally develop send the adhoc build to client for testing of app.

**App Store Profile**

- You will not able to run app on device using this profile.
- It will be used to upload app on App Store or create the release build for distribution on App Store.

Comment: I've added Accounts before.
I added it as an Apple Store profile from the Profiles section on developer.apple.com/account. I added the certificates with keychain access. It also appears in My Certificates.

**The problem still persists.**

Comment: did you created provisioning profiles on developer.apple.com?

Comment: Yes, from Distribution> App Store.

Comment: Then you need to make sure that profile is created for the app site with valid certificate.